# Admob- is it possible to put a link to another App on the market and earn money upon download?

Tags: android, admob, reward

The question is clear I assume though couldn't find a relevant answer on web. For example if my app put a link to another app's PlayStore download page and if user download it can I get money on that? I know and I use normal admob which shows playstore apps to download from time to time  but my question is directly targeting and showing a specific app %100 of the times. Thanks

Comment: I never came across an afilliate marketing model in admob. 
But to show ads for only one app you can create custom ads

Comment: Thank you, if there is this chance for another marketing companies beside Admob, I would still be appreciated to hear about. As said, nothing similar I could find on web unfortunately

Comment: If you look for alternatives, maybe you can find one for your purpose in this list: https://www.quora.com/Which-is-a-better-alternative-to-AdMob-for-Android-ad-platform. The list might be deprecated, but there are plenty alternatives